# Asterisk доступ к удаленному диалплану

Tags: asterisk

Всем привет!

Есть два asterisk сервера связанных между собой по sip. Зарегестрированных друг на друге. Я хочу чтоб на одном сервере при наступлении события в определенном месте диалплана, оно переходило в диалплан на другом сервере (типа Goto). Есть ли такая возможность?

Например представляю так:

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(Dongle/MOBILE_OPERATOR/${EXTEN}) -- на 1 сервере

exten => _X.,n,DongleSendSms(MOBILE_OPERATOR,+1212121212,Outgoing Call) -- на 2 сервере
```

Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

При наступлении события в определенном месте Dial на другой астер и там обрабатываешь дальше звонок.

**Обновление**

По Dial думал Вам надо отправить звонок на другой астер. Для начала надо на втором астере иметь добавочный номер, на него будете отправлять смс, дальше второй астер отправляет смс куда надо.

И для примера http://asterisk-service.com/blog/asterisk-1/post/sip-50 http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+message

Comment: Немного не понял. Мне вообще надо реализовать Sms. Приходит смс на модем на первый астер и она же должна отправляться с другого модема со второго астера. Куда тут вставлять Dial не понял.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне вообще надо реализовать Sms. Приходит смс на модем на первый астер
>   и она же должна отправляться с другого модема со второго астера.

Поробуйте использовать [MessageSend](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_MessageSend) для передачи содержания смс с первого сервера на второй.

Comment: Ок, попробую. Благодарю.